# Preview changing default fullscreen view option to continuous scroll

Tags: preview, monterey, fullscreen, macos

I would like to open preview windows in full screen and I would like to see them in continuous scroll mode as default. I already changed opening for the first time to continuous scroll it works for small preview windows but when I go to full screen mode, it becomes 2 page view which is frustrating and every time I have to do cmd+1.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I can confirm that I experience the same 2-page issue with the full-screen mode while using Preview (v11.0) on macOS Monterey (v12.3). Sadly this appears to be going on for many years as you can see from the "[how do I make preview show only one page at a time in full screen](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6984707)" question posted in another forum seven years ago!

Comment: Take a look at the suggested AppleScript in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105521/359458) if expanding Preview to near-full-screen-only would be OK for you and if there is only one display connected to your Mac. I suggest you check out the [Magnet app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12) (unfortunately not free) if you are using more than one display. The Center command (Ctrl-Alt-Return) in Magnet expands nearly any app window, including Preview, to near-full-screen without triggering the 2-page view, even when there is more than one display connected.